# Trying to grab git info about a WordPress theme from within a plugin

Tags: php, git, wordpress

Creating a WordPress plugin that will retrieve the commit info from select plugins and themes for development purposes. The goal is to have that info be copied to the clipboard once a button is clicked from the admin toolbar.

The issue I am having is grabbing the git info. I have tried getting data with `exec('git rev-parse --short HEAD')` but have not had any luck. Of course running `git rev-parse --short HEAD` from within the plugin will only show that plugins info.

Am I going about this wrong? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What does "have not had any luck" mean? Do you get the wrong hash? An error message? Something else?

Comment: @Chris It's just been returning 1 from an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [in this *build* script](https://github.com/rmccue/wpqi/blob/master/build.php#L67-L74), you need to make sure you are in the right folder:

```
//Time to set the Build Date and Revision.
$date = date( 'Y-m-d' );
$revision = '';
if ( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/.git/HEAD' ) ) {
    $revision = trim( exec( 'git rev-parse --short HEAD' ) );
    $out_contents = preg_replace( '#\$wpqi_version = \'([^\']+)\';#', '$wpqi_version = \'$1-' . $revision . '\';', $out_contents );
}
$out_contents = str_replace( '/*BuildDate*/', $date, $out_contents );
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this :) I actually realized I was using exec from wp-admin so i changed the hook so it now runs from within `admin_menu`. Also found somewhere that appending `2>&1` to your command in exec helps?

Comment: @JoeFusco it does help indeed, to hide any warning/not blocking error message